# All but one of my elseif loops is running - what is wrong with my syntax?

Tags: powershell, if-statement, bitlocker

I am writing a script that checks for a registry key property created by a Bitlocker GPO, checks to see if the device is already protected and if the key is present and the device is not protected then encrypts the device.

I've tested each of these functions individually and they all work, and they all seem to work in the context of the script, outputting the right loop, however when I run the whole script at once, the only loop that DOESN'T work is the loop where the encrypting function runs.

I have the exit codes here because I am using Manage Engine to push out the script to a few remote devices around our estate and I would like to be able to see easily where the script is failing so I can deploy something else.

```
# FUNCTION - Function created to check existence of Active Directory GPO
Function Test-RegistryValue {
$regPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\FVE'
$regPropertyName = 'ActiveDirectoryBackup'

# Value of registry key ported into a script-level variable accessible from outside the function
  $regValue = (Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $regPath -Name $regPropertyName -ErrorAction ignore)
     if ($regValue -eq 1)
       {
         $script:regExit = 0
       } 

# If the key exists but is not set to write back    
     elseif ($regValue -eq 0) 
     { 
        $script:regExit = 1
     }
# If the registry property doesn't exist
     else 
     {
       $script:regExit = 5
     }

} 

# FUNCTION - Function tests if BitLocker protection is already on
function Test-TBBitlockerStatus {$BLinfo = Get-Bitlockervolume

if($blinfo.ProtectionStatus -eq 'On' -and $blinfo.EncryptionPercentage -eq '100')
    {
      return $true
    }
else 
    {
     return $false
    }
}

# FUNCTION - This function is the actual encryption script
Function Enable-TBBitlocker {
Add-BitLockerKeyProtector -MountPoint $env:SystemDrive -RecoveryPasswordProtector 

$RecoveryKey = (Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint $env:SystemDrive).KeyProtector | Where-Object {$_.KeyProtectorType -eq "RecoveryPassword"} 

Manage-bde -protectors -adbackup $env:SystemDrive -id $RecoveryKey[0].KeyProtectorId

Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint $env:SystemDrive -UsedSpaceOnly -TpmProtector -SkipHardwareTest
}

# MAIN SCRIPT
# Running the GPO check function
Test-RegistryValue
Test-TBBitlockerStatus
$regExit

    if ($regExit -eq 1) 
        {
             Write-Host 'Key present but writeback not enabled.'
             exit 51
        }
# Exit if GPO not present
    elseif ($regExit -eq 5) 
        {
             Write-Host 'GPO not present.'
              exit 55
        }
# Test for device already being encrypted
    elseif ((Test-TBBitlockerStatus -eq True) -and ($regExit -eq 0))
        {
            Write-Host 'Writeback enabled but device already protected.'
            exit 61
        }
# Test for device being encrypted and writeback is not enabled.
    elseif ((Test-TBBitlockerStatus -eq True) -and ($regExit -ge 1))
        {
            Write-Host 'Device already protected but AD writeback is not enabled.'
            exit 65
        }
    elseif ((Test-TBBitlockerStatus -eq False) -and ($regExit -eq 0)) 
        {
             Enable-TBBitlocker | Write-Output
             Write-Host 'Encryption successful.'
             exit 10 
        }
```

The Write-Host comments are so I can see where it's failing or succeeding. If I manually change the key value to 1 or 0, or encrypt the device and run the script the correct loop runs, however when the device is not encrypted and has the key in the registry, it does absolutely nothing. The exit code doesn't change, there's no output to the host.

I have the output included before the main if scope to see if the values are being set correctly, which they are but that final encryption function loop does not run at all.

Comment: ```Test-TBBitlockerStatus -eq True``` if true should be a string u missed the quotes, otherwise the dollar =  'True'/$true. and you definitly get exceptions...

Comment: The script exits if `$regExit` is either 1 or 5. The condition `elseif ((Test-TBBitlockerStatus -eq True) -and ($regExit -ge 1))` will never be reached (the exit code can never be 65).

Comment: So I have qualified the top two loops with -and statements for 

 if ($regExit -eq 1) 
        {
             Write-Host 'Key present but writeback not enabled.'
             exit 51
        }
# Exit if GPO not present
    elseif ($regExit -eq 5) 
        {
             Write-Host 'GPO not present.'
              exit 55
        }

with -and statements for Test-TBBitlockerStatus -eq False so it does try to run on RegExit -eq 1 or 5 AND Test-TBBitlockerStatus -eq False but when I try to run that it doesn't output any of the write hosts in the loops.